# Как сделать роли в laravel для контент-менеджера, админа, пользователя, модератора?

Tags: laravel

Как сделать роли в laravel для контент-менеджера, админа, пользователя, модератора?

Answer (score 1):

Вот хороший и удобный пакет для ролей и прав доступа в laravel. [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)